# Dynamically generated div onclick event

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, live

I want add an onclick event, to a button which generated dynamically with ajax.
How can I do this?

I have that code which generating the content, and when we click to that item I want a popup window.

```
function getTableData() {

    $.post( 'loader.php', getGetStr(), function( data ) {

        Object.size = function(obj) {
            var size = 0, key;
            for (key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
            }
            return size;
        };
        data = $.parseJSON(data)['query-data'];
        var leng = Object.size(data);

        var html = '';

        for(var i = 0; i<leng; i++) {
             html += '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>\n\
                        <td>'+data[i].buy_type+'</td>\n\
                        <td>'+data[i].prop_type+'</td>\n\
                        <td>'+data[i].district+'</td>\n\
                        <td>'+data[i].street+'</td>\n\
                        <td>'+data[i].room_min+'</td>\n\
                        <td>'+data[i].room_max+'</td>\n\
                        <td>'+data[i].price_min+' mFt</td>\n\
                        <td>'+data[i].price_max+' mFt</td>\n\
                        <td>'+data[i].condition_type+'</td>\n\
                        <td>'+data[i].heat_type+'</td>\n\
                        <td>'+data[i].lift_type+'</td>\n\
                        <td>'+data[i].parking_type+'</td>\n\
                        <td><img src="style/images/icons/delete.png" id="'+data[i].id+'" class="delete-searching-item"/></td>\n\
                    </tr>';
         }

         $('table').append(html);
         $('.delete-searching-item').on('click',function() {
             var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    alert(id);
                    $('#submit-delete').append('<input type="hidden" name="to-delete" value="' + id + '">');
                    $('#why-delete').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: jQuery's on function add events to elements even if they are generated with ajax. You can use http://api.jquery.com/on/ this on generated elements in your document load or something.

Comment: And? Does it not work? What symptoms do you see? What is it doing that you don't expect? It certainly looks like it would hook up the click event. (It also looks like it would hook it up twice on some elements, if you call `getTableData` twice, because you're not emptying the table but you are hooking up all existing cells once you add [including the ones that were already there and hooked up last time].)

Comment: I have a simliar use.
I've added an onClick function to each <a> element
  $(document).ready(function() {
 $("a").click( function() {
   ...

but if I add content dynamicly to the DOM, and inside that content is a <a> element, a click on that new element will not be handled by the onClick-handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
$('table').on('click','.delete-searching-item',function() {
```

Since you added `img.delete-searching-item` after dom you need to refer to an element that didn't change, `table` for example. And with `.on()` you can "get it back" in dom.

So your whole code:

```
function getTableData() {
    $.post('loader.php', getGetStr(), function(data) {
        Object.size = function(obj) {
            var size = 0,
                key;
            for (key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
            }
            return size;
        };
        data = $.parseJSON(data)['query-data'];
        var leng = Object.size(data);
        var html = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < leng; i++) {
            html += '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>\n\
                                <td>' + data[i].buy_type + '</td>\n\
                                <td>' + data[i].prop_type + '</td>\n\
                                <td>' + data[i].district + '</td>\n\
                                <td>' + data[i].street + '</td>\n\
                                <td>' + data[i].room_min + '</td>\n\
                                <td>' + data[i].room_max + '</td>\n\
                                <td>' + data[i].price_min + ' mFt</td>\n\
                                <td>' + data[i].price_max + ' mFt</td>\n\
                                <td>' + data[i].condition_type + '</td>\n\
                                <td>' + data[i].heat_type + '</td>\n\
                                <td>' + data[i].lift_type + '</td>\n\
                                <td>' + data[i].parking_type + '</td>\n\
                                <td><img src="style/images/icons/delete.png" id="' + data[i].id + '" class="delete-searching-item"/></td>\n\
                            </tr>';
        }
        $('table').append(html);
        $('table').on('click','.delete-searching-item',function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            alert(id);
            $('#submit-delete').append('<input type="hidden" name="to-delete" value="' + id + '">');
            $('#why-delete').fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: But note that in the OP's code, the elements **were** in the DOM by the time he/she called `on`. The `on` call was **after** the `append` call on the table. So they were being found. Delegation may be a better approach, but it's not lack of delegation or trying to hook up elements that aren't in the DOM that's the problem. (It's unclear what the OP is even saying the problem *is*.)

Answer (score -1):

Please check  below

```
$(".delete-searching-item").live("click", function(){  }); // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(".delete-searching-item", "click", function(){  }); // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on("click", ".delete-searching-item", function(){  }); // jQuery 1.7+
```